# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, export, es6-modules

I have a problem with my webpack project, so I was trying to import one class to another and instantiate it but suddenly an error appear in my console and my program stopped working, it was this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization
```

This is the code of the class were I am trying to import my another class (that is PopUpPlugin):

```
import PopupPlugin from './popupPlugin.js';

export const addSearchBtnEvent = (weatherUI) => {
  const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.weather__search');
  
  searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    weatherUI.style.opacity = '1';
    weatherUI.style.visibility = 'visible';
  })
}

export const addSearchExitEvent = (weatherUI) => {
  const weatherExit = document.querySelector('.weather__search-exit');
  
  weatherExit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    weatherUI.style.opacity = '0';
    weatherUI.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  })
}

const popupObj = new PopupPlugin();

class searchDashboard {
  constructor() {
    
  }
  
  setInputEvent() {
    const inputSearch = document.querySelector('.weather__city-search');
    const inputSearchBtn = document.querySelector('.weather__search-btn');
    
    inputSearchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const inputSearchVal = inputSearch.value;
      
      this.validateStr(inputSearchVal);
    });
  }
  
  validateStr() {
    const onlyLettersAndSpaces = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*$/;
    
    if(str.trim().length > 0 && str.match(onlyLettersAndSpaces)) {
      const strValue = str.toLowerCase().trim().replace(' ', '+');
      
      this.popupObj.searchCoincidences(strValue, 'weather__search-ui');
    }
  }
}

export default searchDashboard;
```

I don't actually know why this is happening, I also tried to instantiate it inside the constructor and it worked but it sended me the error of an stack overflow.

PD: If someone needs it here is the code of the PopupPlugin. (Here is what was working to me that was instantiating the class inside the constructor until the stack overflow error appeared)

```
import ManageWeatherDashboard from './manageWeatherDashboard.js';
import { getFetch, repeatAppend } from './weatherHelpers.js';

class popupPlugin {
  constructor() {
    this.manageWeatherDashboardObj = new ManageWeatherDashboard();
  }

  validateStr(str) {
    const onlyLettersAndSpaces = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*$/;
    
    if(str.trim().length > 0 && str.match(onlyLettersAndSpaces)) {
      const strValue = str.toLowerCase().trim().replace(' ', '+');
      
      return strValue;
    }
  }
  
  searchCoincidences(val, parent) {
    getFetch(`https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=${val}`)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(data => {
        const parentResults = document.querySelector('.'+parent);
        
        parentResults.innerHTML = '';
        
        const dataArr = JSON.parse(data)
        
        if(dataArr.length >= 15) {
          let resVal;
          
          for(let i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
            resVal = this.addDOMResultCoincidences(parent, dataArr[i].title,
              dataArr[i].woeid);
          }
          
          this.whenClickCoincidence(resVal);
        } else {
          let resVal;
          
          dataArr.forEach(el => {
            resVal = this.addDOMResultCoincidences(parent, el.title, el.woeid);
          })
          
          this.whenClickCoincidence(resVal);
        }
        
      })
  }
  
  addDOMResultCoincidences(parentBlock, name, id) {
    const args = Array.from(arguments);
    
    if(args[0] === 'popup__results') {
      const popupResults = document.querySelector('.popup__results');

      const divResult = document.createElement('div');
      divResult.className = 'popup__result';
      divResult.setAttribute('data-woeid', id);
      
      const spanResultName = document.createElement('span');
      spanResultName.className = 'popup__result-name';
      
      const cityReturn = document.createTextNode(args[1]);
      
      spanResultName.appendChild(cityReturn);
      
      divResult.appendChild(spanResultName);
      
      popupResults.prepend(divResult);
      
      return divResult;
    }
    
    if(args[0] === 'weather__search-ui') {
      const weatherUI = document.querySelector('.weather__search-ui');
      
      const divResult = document.createElement('div');
      divResult.className = 'weather__search-result';
      divResult.setAttribute('data-woeid', id);
      
      const spanResultName = document.createElement('span');
      const spanResultNameText = document.createTextNode(args[1]);
      spanResultName.className = 'weather__city-result';
      spanResultName.appendChild(spanResultNameText);
      
      const iconResult = document.createElement('i');
      iconResult.className = 'fa fa-arrow-right weather__go-result';
      
      repeatAppend([spanResultName, iconResult], divResult);
      
      weatherUI.appendChild(divResult);
      
      return divResult;
    }
  }
  
  // When click a coincidence in search field
  
  whenClickCoincidence(el) {
    const woeId = el.getAttribute('data-woeid');
    
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let handler = 0;
      
      if(handler === 0) {
        getFetch(`https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/${woeId}/`)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
            
            const weatherNext6Days = data.consolidated_weather;
            
            this.manageWeatherDashboardObj.changeWeatherBar(weatherNext6Days[0], data.title);
            
            weatherNext6Days.slice(1, 6).forEach(el => {
              this.manageWeatherDashboardObj.nextFiveDays(el);
            })
            
            this.manageWeatherDashboardObj.updateStadistics(weatherNext6Days[0]);
            
            popup.style.opacity = '0';
            popup.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          })
      }
      
      handler += 1;
    })
  }
}

export default popupPlugin;
```

Comment: Which version of Webpack are you using?

Comment: Sorry for leaving this comment inactive, i have the most recent version in npm 5.12.0

Comment: How do you run Webpack? Via CLI? Via npm run? Any other?

Comment: I run webpack via cli.

Answer (score 72):

This might be caused by a cyclic dependencies (i.e. moduleA imports module B and vice versa at the same time). Take a deeper look at your code.

Comment: I had this problem and it was a matter of circular dependencies

Comment: Same here. Plus, I want to add (unfortunately edit queue is full) that the cyclic dependency might not be anywhere nothing recent you've done. I spent some time commenting-out code until I found that the module that was causing it was there from the beginning and long before the problem arised. Also in the stack trace of the problem you might find a reference to the module that is causing it even if it is through its index file.

Answer (score 16):

I faced the same issue when I moved the import statement for the redux store below some import of a local module that was dealing with some reducer reference from the store. Moving the `import store from ./store` upwards resolved this issue for me.

Try fixing the order of imports in your files.

Comment: FWIW my issue was instantiating a singleton based on a imported modules. Similar to your suggestion, it was fixed by moving instantiation of singleton to a check within a function call to get the singleton.

Comment: Thanks! It does work for the same problem

Answer (score 14):

Had this problem, after upgrading from webpack 4 to webpack 5, and, yes, it was a circular dependency *in my case*.

Furthermore I found this blog [How to Eliminate Circular Dependencies from Your JavaScript Project](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/06/25/circular-dependencies-javascript/) which led me to https://github.com/aackerman/circular-dependency-plugin

Plopped the plugin into my webpack dev config, as per sample on github, then spent some time reading its output figuring out where I went wrong.  Fixing things was pretty easy once I knew the problem - it had been a pretty basic error.

circular-dependency-plugin@5.2.2 works on webpack 4 apparently, and I can confirm it works on webpack@5.73.0 as well.  Saved me lots of time :-)  You can take it out of webpack dev config after it's done its work.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was due to circular import. Meaning, that two modules are exporting and importing contents form each other

Answer (score 3):

For anyone whose issue is not a circular dependency, it could also be a missing import.

In my case, using Material UI 5, I forgot the line `import { styled } from "@mui/styles";`, which gave me this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization`

instead of the usual `ReferenceError: MyModule is not defined` missing import error.

Answer (score 2):

Using my IDE auto import I had something like:

```
import useStore, { useCart } from "../lib/store"
```

Everything was working fine for awhile! But then I got the same error until I changed my import to be like this:

```
import { useStore, useCart } from "../lib/store"
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case, I was just trying to call the dispatch function before the store had fully loaded - i.e. *store.dispatch()*

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was caused by importing from a common `index.ts` file where the affected object is also exported.

For example say my `./widgets/index.ts` looked like:

```
export { WidgetA } from './widgets/object-a';
export { WidgetB } from './widgets/object-b';
```

And in `./widgets/object-b.ts` this would cause the Webpack error:

```
import { WidgetA } from '../widgets';
```

However this would work:

```
import { WidgetA } from '../widgets/object-a';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day! This issue looks quite weird, do you know why the 1st example doesn't work (with `./`) while the 2nd (with `../`) does?

Comment: My guess is that it's still a circular dependency thing, but its obscured by the transpiler. I've noticed this issue in NextJS when mixing Server Side and Client Side code, and in Storybook, both of which transpile in their own weird way. @haptn

Answer (score 0):

Have same issue in nextjs project.
Switching to previous versions or reinstalling `node_modules/` - did not help.

Solution - remove `build/` directory and restart build.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the entry-point file that used the following syntax:

```js
export default <symbol>;
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, inside the **store/test/fetchSmth.saga.ts** file, I was trying to import a function not from the store.

just moving this function to the **store/test/utils.ts** file helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This is error also can be occur by not clearing the export.
export default componentsname => so also check the all files component name is right as component name or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also hit this problem, caused by circular component reference - Component **A** includes component **B** which includes component **A**. (**A->B->C->A** in my case)

The solutioin is in the Vue documentation (Vue.js 2 in my case) [Circular References Between Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html?redirect=true#Circular-References-Between-Components)

Second proposed decision fix my case:

```
components: {
   circularComponent: () => import('./CircularComponent.vue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually experimented this, and to solve it, went from

```
const Field = () => {}

export default Field
```

to this

```
export default function Field () {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because you used circle import.

For me, I used encapsulated axios to request in mobx store, and I also used some data from mobx store in encapsulated axios.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

This isn't exactly what's causing the same error to occur for me.

Mine were caused by calling things like useState, useEffect and firebase() outside the main functional Component Block. This is very dumb but I somehow completely missed it.

Hope it helps anyone from the future who had the same problem as mine.