# Webpack Uncaught Reference Error in the console of React Redux project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

In my React Redux app, it just shows a white screen after running npm start. There is one error in the console-
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization     at Module.default (userSlice.js:22:1)     at Module../src/firebase.js (firebase.js:13:1)     at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)     at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)     at Module../src/screens/SignUpScreen.js (ProfileScreen.js:42:1)     at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)     at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)     at Module../src/screens/LoginScreen.js (HomeScreen.js:29:1)`

any idea what the error means/ how to troubleshoot it?

I looked at all of the lines that the error references, and most of them are when I'm exporting a component.

Comment: Maybe you can find the solution right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038253/uncaught-referenceerror-cannot-access-webpack-default-export-before-initi