# Laravel Vuejs Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I'm not able to see what's the problem here.
Compiling with npm run watch I get the below error.
I try differents things nothing, no clue where the error coming from

Error in the Console

```
> survey-front.js:126297 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization
    at Module.default (survey-front.js:126297:42)
    at Module../resources/js/router.js (RecordRTC.js:700:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (survey-front.js:141859:42)
```

file survey-front.js

```
   import Vue from 'vue'

   Vue.component('survey-show', require('./components/SurveyShow.vue').default)
   Vue.component('survey-language', require('./components/SurveySetLanguage.vue').default)


    new Vue({
    el: "#surveyElement"
})
```

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.27.9",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.43",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.8",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "survey-knockout": "^1.9.26",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "webpack": "^5.72.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "inputmask": "^5.0.5",
        "survey-vue": "^1.9.26",
        "surveyjs-widgets": "^1.9.26",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
        "vuetify": "^1.0.18"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '\_\_WEBPACK\_DEFAULT\_EXPORT\_\_' before initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038253/uncaught-referenceerror-cannot-access-webpack-default-export-before-initi)

Comment: @KenWhite No and still no clue where the error coming from