# I have this error in building react app in server console "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Row.js:18

```
   Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization
at Module.default (Row.js:18:1)
at ./src/axios.js (axios.js:2:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./src/Banner.js (App.js:20:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./src/App.js (bundle.js:18:65
```

How do i remove this error whenever i use fetchUrl, useState and useEffect in row.js file it shows this error.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an error import issue. Check whether all the file imports are working fine or not. Or check if you are calling some dependent function before the parent function is loaded. Also, check this for reference-- [Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038253/uncaught-referenceerror-cannot-access-webpack-default-export-before-initi)