# ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization

Tags: node.js, webpack, version, upgrade, referenceerror

This is my error, I donot know whats wrong, I am upgrading my project from node 10 to node 18 and I upgraded packages and everything and now I am stuck here for a while  now

```
webpack://fas-backend/./src/express/routes/products/product.model.js?:3
/* harmony export */   "default": () => (__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__)
                                         ^

ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization
    at Module.default (webpack://fas-backend/./src/express/routes/products/product.model.js?:3:42)
    at eval (webpack://fas-backend/./src/express/routes/projectProducts/projectProducts.model.js?:38:66)
    at ./src/express/routes/projectProducts/projectProducts.model.js (C:\Excersys\FASAPI3\dist\server.js:2059:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Excersys\FASAPI3\dist\server.js:2963:41)
    at eval (webpack://fas-backend/./src/express/routes/products/product.model.js?:30:97)
    at ./src/express/routes/products/product.model.js (C:\Excersys\FASAPI3\dist\server.js:1549:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Excersys\FASAPI3\dist\server.js:2963:41)
    at eval (webpack://fas-backend/./src/express/routes/operation/operation.helper.js?:7:81)
    at ./src/express/routes/operation/operation.helper.js (C:\Excersys\FASAPI3\dist\server.js:1239:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Excersys\FASAPI3\dist\server.js:2963:41)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

this is packege.json file

```
{
  "name": "******",
  "version": "******",
  "description": "*********",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && node dist/server.js",
    "buildDev": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && webpack --mode development --config webpack.dev.config.js --watch",
    "devBuild": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && webpack --mode development --config webpack.dev.config.js",
    "buildProd": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.prod.config.js",
    "deploy-fas": "cp .fas.env .env && npm run buildProd && gcloud config set project faslive-51622 && gcloud app deploy",
    "deploy-mexmax": "cp .mexmax.env .env && npm run buildProd && gcloud config set project mexmax-backend && gcloud app deploy",
    "deploy-westgate": "cp .westgate.env .env && npm run buildProd && gcloud config set project westgate-1504085677899 && gcloud app deploy",
    "deploy-westgate-dev": "cp .westgate.dev.env .env && npm run devBuild && gcloud config set project westgatedash-dev && gcloud app deploy",
    "deploy-nova": "cp .fwd.env .env && npm run buildProd && gcloud config set project fwd-api-286114 && gcloud app deploy"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": [
      "src",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "delay": "2500"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "~8.5.0",
    "@google-cloud/tasks": "^3.0.5",
    "@google/maps": "^1.1.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "amazon-mws": "0.0.30",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "ebay-api": "^7.1.3",
    "express": "4.18.2",
    "express-validation": "^1.0.2",
    "faker": "^6.6.6",
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "http-status": "^1.3.2",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "icontact-api": "^0.3.0",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "json-2-csv": "^3.7.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "luxon": "^3.0.1",
    "magento-api-rest": "^2.0.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "node-async-loop": "^1.2.2",
    "node-constantcontact": "^2.0.0",
    "oauth-1.0a": "^2.2.6",
    "parse-url": "^8.1.0",
    "payload-validator": "^1.0.4",
    "randomstring": "^1.2.2",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "sass-loader": "13.2.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.27.0",
    "streamifier": "^0.1.1",
    "throttled-queue": "^2.1.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "xhr2": "^0.2.0",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "xmlbuilder": "^15.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.29.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "nodemon-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

this is webpack config file

```
const path = require('path');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const webpack = require('webpack'); // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const NodemonPlugin = require('nodemon-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
  entry: {
    server: './src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  mode: argv.mode,
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new NodemonPlugin(),
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
});
```

I need to upgrade my project to react 18 from node 10 and upgraded my packages and everything and solved many issues and everything and I am stuck at this one for quite a while now tried everything, Need help.

Comment: See this very similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038253/uncaught-referenceerror-cannot-access-webpack-default-export-before-initi

Comment: went through this but nothing there works and applies to my situation